# Copy a dmp into the same database

Tags: oracle

UPDATE: rephrase the question 
I want to copy my schema to another schema, is there a way to copy other that expdp/impdp, since the export schema is already there in the destination database

I didn't find an answer on the internet.
I appreciate your help

OLD: before rephrase
I have a 40GB`.dmp` db against a user `ieulive22apr`. Now, I want the same dmp on a different user, like `ieulive11may` on the same Database where the source dmp.
I can export the dmp and re-import it, but I'm asking, can I copy the dump file with a different user for a faster time.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [REMAP_SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927) import data pump's parameter.

Syntax is

```
REMAP_SCHEMA=source_schema:target_schema
```

which, in your case, means

```
REMAP_SCHEMA=ieulive22apr:ieulive11may
```

Comment: I don't have the dmp user as a file, it only exist in the database. I edited my questions and remove the word "file"

Comment: What exactly do you call a "dmp"? In Oracle *world*, it stands for a file that is result of **export** utility (be it data pump, or the "original" export). So, if you want to copy contents of one schema to another, perform data pump **export**. It will create a .dmp file. Then use data pump **import** with the REMAP_SCHEMA parameter to import contents of that .dmp file into another schema.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So in these terms, what I want to do is copy the contents of one schema to another, and I asked if there's a way faster than expdp/impdp, since the schema is already there on the destination database. Thanks again

Comment: There's none, as far as I can tell. You *could* do it manually, copy table-by-table (as well as all your procedures, triggers, packages, ...), but I'd say that it would be actually slower.

Comment: Export/import _is_ the tool that oracle designed for this very purpose.  With expdp, it is possible to export to a db link instead of a file, so that could cut out a step.